# Correct way to handle exception in hibernate/jpa and JUnit5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit5

I would like to know, the best way to handle exception when I try to create and persist an object in the Database.

So I have a table named Rule with getters and setters :

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "hint", nullable = false)
    private String hint;

    @Column(name = "help", nullable = false)
    private String help;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "language", nullable = false)
    private Language language;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "rule")
    @Column(name = "user_rule")
    private Set<UserRule> user_rule;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
    private Set<Sentence> sentence;
```

And I have the method create who add the object in the database :

```
 public static Rule create(EntityManagerFactory factory, String type, String hint, String help, Language language) {
            EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
            EntityTransaction transaction = null;
            Rule new_rule = new Rule();

            try {
                transaction = em.getTransaction();
                transaction.begin();

                new_rule.setType(type);
                new_rule.setHint(hint);
                new_rule.setHelp(help);
                new_rule.setLanguage(language);

                em.persist(new_rule);
                transaction.commit();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            throw ex;

            } finally {
                em.close();
            }

            return new_rule;
    }
```

1. Should I use multiple catch for each exception who methods can throw in the try block ?
2. If my solution is good way to handle it, how can I print a specific message related to the exception `ex` in a good way ?
3. How can I raise an exception in my JUnit5 for the content of the `try` block, to test if an exception is raised (should I raise all exceptions ?)
4. If I pass a null element (who was set at nullable = false)  to the method `create` how errors or exceptions are transmitted (by hibernate/jpa or I should handle it myself as usual ?)

Let me know if you have any other advice !

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

May be below links will give you the best exception handling mechanism.

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-exception-handling-example/

https://blog.takipi.com/5-common-hibernate-exceptions-and-how-to-fix-them/

Comment: Thanks, but I have more questions ! In my exemple 3 Exceptions can be raised. I have learned that it's more relevant to use specifics exceptions, so I was thinking to use an other method and giving the name of the table where the exception is raised and the exception ```e```. Inside I will use ```instanceof``` to throw the good Exception with a relevant message. So in the transactional method I just call the method with the arguments.
Is it a good way in terms of design pattern and performances ? If yes, should I move this method into a different package from my Database description package ?

Comment: Yes , you can do it. It is also good practice to use instanceof keyword to find specific exception and process on it. I believe you are using single method to process all 3 exceptions.